# Php Dynamic Variables Syntax

Tags: php, dynamic, syntax

I am trying to use dynamic variables. I know this syntax works :

```
$my_data->data1;
$my_data->data2;
...
```

Becomes this in a for() loop :

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= nb_of_data ; $i++) {
    ${'my_data->data' . $i};
}
```

But how should I transform these lines ?

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $nb_of_iterations ; $i++) {
    $my_data[$i]->data1;
    $my_data[$i]->data2;
...
```

I tought about this, but it doesn't work :

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $nb_of_iterations ; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0 ; $j <= $nb_of_data ; $j++) {
        ${'my_data[' . $i . ']->data' . $j;
    }
}
```

The number of 'data' is very variable.

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/php-dynamic-variables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer. Here is the right syntax :

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $nb_of_iterations ; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0 ; $j <= $nb_of_data ; $j++) {
        ${'my_data[' . $i . ']'}->data . $j;
    }
}
```

There was too much code beetween the brackets !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make mydata a multidimensional array?

```
$mydata = array();
$data = array(1 => "data",...);
$mydata[] = $data;
```

you can than interate of mydata and each data in it:

```
foreach($mydata as $md){
  foreach($md as $data){
  //do with $data what you want
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't touch the structure of my_data. That is why I tought about dynamic variables.

Comment: can't you use a secon array to put the data from my_data into? 
Imo dynamic variables are kinda risky. storring them in arrays is way safer.

Comment: Why are dynamic variables risky ?

Comment: With arrays you can use `foreach` that blocks you from calling array-parts that don't exist. With dynamic variables you can't prefent that. A small misstake could call a variable that doesn't excists and therefore crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $nb_of_iterations ; $i++) {
    $my_data[$i]->data.$i;
    $my_data[$i]->data2.$i;
}

for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $nb_of_iterations ; $i++) {
        $my_data['$i']->data.'$i';
}
?>
```